# FLUTTER WEB read QR code accessing the camera

Tags: flutter, qr-code, flutter-web

I have the problem of working with **FLUTTER WEB** and I need to read a QR code accessing the camera. From what I have investigated, there is no library for this and in some forums, they suggest using the JS and HTML libraries in web flutter to be able to carry out the implementation.
I also have not found many guides or tutorials on how this is done, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am working on this problem.  The problem is the javascript can't access the camera outside of a secure server.  So I am going to test the javascript on https using ui.platformViewRegistry and dynamically injecting the div reader id.  you use dart.js to access your javascript code in web (html-qrcode.js, html5-qrcode-scanner.js, qrcode).  use window.document to access the dom.  Flutter uses a shadow dom

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: Any update on that problem?

Comment: @GoldenLion have you managed to access the camera with your approch?

Comment: Yes.  I wrote the app in angular and then accessed an external 3rd party javascript library

Comment: see this package https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode

Comment: Another package for flutter web that does the job is https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner